# ToElementMesh[]

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

Could you please help with the following:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
a = 0.1;
b = 0.05;
chi = RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-a, -b}, {a, b}], Rectangle[{-b, -a}, {b, a}]];
DiscretizeRegion[chi];
Omega = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], chi];
DiscretizeRegion[Omega]
ToElementMesh[Omega]["Wireframe"]
```

DiscretizeRegion[] works as expected, but ToElementMesh[] produces an unexpected result. What could be the difference?

My outputs are as follows:

[image: from DiscretizeRegion]
[image: from ToElementMesh]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by unexpected. If you do not see the region hole, then you might want to upgrade your version of Mathematica. Alternatively you could try

```
ToElementMesh[Omega, "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0}}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

If that's not the issue, you'd need to clarify a bit what you would have expected.

Another alternative is to try use

```
ToElementMesh[Omega, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"]["Wireframe"]
```

And/or a variation of the above. But I recommend an update to the latest version of Mathematica.

Comment: I see a hole, but the hole is with irregular shape. I am using version 10.0. Which version do you use?

Comment: @S.E.A, see update.

Comment: Everything is OK in 10.1.