# ToElementMesh of Region with Hole

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

When I try to mesh the following region it fails. Why? Is there a workaround?

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 1;  (*length *)
ht = 0.125; (* height *)
wd = 0.5; (* width *)
hwd = 0.25; (* hole width *)
reg = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, -wd/2, 0}, {Len, wd/2, ht}], 
  Cuboid[{Len/2 - hwd/2, -hwd/2, 0}, {Len/2 + hwd/2, hwd/2, ht}]];
Region[reg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
```

> DiscretizeGraphics::rnimpl: The function DiscretizeGraphics is not implemented for Tetrahedron[<<1>>].

Version 11.3 for Windows.

Comment: Precedents are https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83231/toelementmesh and
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84773/3d-fem-with-holes/130579#130579

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why on earth a `Tetrahedron`-wrapped list of 3D-simplices is returned by `RegionDifference`, but this helps to circumvent it:

```
R1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   Cuboid[{0, -wd/2, 0}, {Len, wd/2, ht}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> ∞
   ];
R2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   Cuboid[{Len/2 - hwd/2, -hwd/2, 0}, {Len/2 + hwd/2, hwd/2, ht}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> ∞
   ];
reg = RegionDifference[R1, R2];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg]
```

> ElementMesh[{{0., 1.}, {-0.25, 0.25}, {0., 0.125}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 13557 ">"]}]

Comment: This does the job. Thanks.

Comment: Hugh, you're welcome.

Answer (score 6):

May I suggest using [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package? It offers more flexibility and alternative solutions for generating meshes on simple geometries.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 1;(*length*)
ht = 0.125;(*height*)
wd = 0.5;(*width*)
hwd = 0.25;(*hole width*)

region2D = RegionDifference[
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Len, wd}],
   Rectangle[{(Len - hwd)/2, (wd - hwd)/2}, {(Len + hwd)/2, (wd + hwd)/2}]
];

Needs["MeshTools`"];
mesh2D = SmoothenMesh@TriangleToQuadMesh@ToElementMesh[
    region2D,
    "MeshOrder" -> 1,
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}
]

mesh2D["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh2D]

```
mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, ht, 5]

mesh3D["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue]]
```

[image: mesh3D]

Comment: Package looks excellent. I will look further. Are the elements produced capable of being used in NDSolve for finite element analysis? I think NDSolve can only use cuboid or tetrahedral elements. Am I correct?

Comment: @Hugh Thank you! I am constantly improving the package to make it of production quality. 
Yes, of course, you can use this mesh with `HexahedronElement`s in `NDSolve` and related functions. You can also create a "structured" mesh on you simple shape and get very high quality mesh with lower number of DOF.